# Why does my implementation of "is 2D point inside 2D polygon" have slightly different results on either side of the same axis?

Tags: collision-detection, movement, tiles, ruby

My 2D game is tile-based, 16 pixels per tile. Colliders are defined by an array of points which determine a polygon. With debugging enabled (as it is in the photos) those colliders are outlined with red lines. You can see this on the player and on the water tiles I am using to explain the issue.

The following two photos are both what happens when the player moves leftwards into the collider of the water tile.

[image]
[image]
The difference between these two photos is the fact that the player's collider collides with the tile collider on its corner. The second picture represents the desired effect. I should clarify that in the photos, the second (lower) water tile is not required to be there to have the same effect.

Currently this issue only happens when approaching a tile collider moving *upwards* or *leftwards*. This has the effect of preventing the player from moving along the tile into a new tile - the corner of the adjacent tile catches the player's collider and stops movement.

Here is the code I'm using to determine if a point is within a polygon. This function is called on each point that makes up the collider of the player.

```
def self.point_in_poly(testx, testy, *poly)
  return false if outside_bounding_box?(testx, testy, *poly)

  point_in_poly = false
  i = -1
  j = poly.count - 1
  while (i += 1) < poly.count
    a_point_on_polygon = poly[i]
    trailing_point_on_polygon = poly[j]
    if point_is_between_the_ys_of_the_line_segment?([testx, testy], a_point_on_polygon, trailing_point_on_polygon)
      if ray_crosses_through_line_segment?([testx, testy], a_point_on_polygon, trailing_point_on_polygon)
        point_in_poly = !point_in_poly
      end
    end
    j = i
  end
  return point_in_poly
end

private

def self.point_is_between_the_ys_of_the_line_segment?(point, a_point_on_polygon, trailing_point_on_polygon)
  (a_point_on_polygon[1] <= point[1] && point[1] < trailing_point_on_polygon[1]) || 
  (trailing_point_on_polygon[1] <= point[1] && point[1] < a_point_on_polygon[1])
end

def self.ray_crosses_through_line_segment?(point, a_point_on_polygon, trailing_point_on_polygon)
  (point[0] < (trailing_point_on_polygon[0] - a_point_on_polygon[0]) * (point[1] - a_point_on_polygon[1]) / 
             (trailing_point_on_polygon[1] - a_point_on_polygon[1]) + a_point_on_polygon[0])
end

def self.outside_bounding_box?(x, y, *poly)
  max_x, max_y, min_x, min_y = nil
  x_coords = poly.map {|p| p[0]}
  y_coords = poly.map {|p| p[1]}

  max_x = x_coords.max
  max_y = y_coords.max
  min_x = x_coords.min
  min_y = y_coords.min

  return x < min_x || x > max_x || y < min_y || y > max_y
end
```

Any insight as to why this might be happening at only at leftwards and upwards directions is appreciated.